# spark sql nested JSON with filed name number ParseException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have nested JSON in my Kafka topic which I consume using spark streaming.

{"x" : {
    "y" : "CLASSIC",
    "z" : {
      "100" : {
        "user" : 0.0,
        "AA" : 0,
        "BB" : 0,
        "CC" : 2
      }
    }

when I try to  spark.sql(s"""select x.y.z.100.user from $tableInMemory """)
Im geeting :
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: extraneous input '.100' expecting {, '(', ',', '.',

however when I try without spark sql: myDataFrame.select("x.y.z.100.user").show(false)  It's  working.
Any Idea???

Answer (score 0):

It is not a valid SQL document:

- It is missing opening curly bracket (`{`).
- It has extraneous `,` after nested `CC` field.